# Limitations of web service in Moodle

Tags: web-services, moodle

I'm going to integrate a Moodle-based application into my website wherein all data/activities being posted in this Moodle-based application can be retrieved by my website and vice versa.

So, is the Moodle web service enough to access all the data in that Moodle application?

Comment: What do you need to integrate?

Comment: What kind of website is "my website"? A "normal" html website, or some other type of server-side application (like Moodle/Joomla/Drupal/etc.)?  What info do you want to retrieve from Moodle? "all data/activities being posted in this Moodle-based application" could mean anything...

Also, how to you want to get this info from Moodle into your site? Must Moodle push the data to your other site as-and-when the info is created or modified in Moodle? Or do you want your website to pull the info from Moodle on a regular basis?

Comment: Well, its just a normal website, but it was developed using python language.
So, all I want to retrieve is the important data such as accounts, courses and activities, etc. for example, if i have an account in Moodle-site, then i can simply login to my website using my credentials in Moodle-site, as well as if I create an activity in a particular course in Moodle-site, then I can simply view it in my website(and vice versa). In other words, I just want to "connect" the Moodle-site into my website.

Comment: So, my question is how? Should i use the Moodle web services to connect it? and is it enough to access/retrieve those data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use web services. No, not all data is accessible out-of-the-box.

Things you can do with the webservices:

- Retrieve a list of users, courses, assignments
- Upload files
- Create notes
- Send messages
- Enrol to courses, groups, cohorts
- Check grades

On your Moodle site turn on web services and go to /admin/webservice/documentation.php to get a full list of existing functions you can call.

You can see some examples of this implemented in the Moodle Mobile App:

- User: http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Mobile_app
- Dev: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_Mobile

If these satisfy your requirements then yes web services should be sufficient as they are.

If they do not then you can extend the web services as a local plugin to provide richer functionality, which would be limited by your development capacity rather than the system itself. To port all of the features of some modules to web services would be a significant undertaking, but there are some low-hanging fruit to get activity lists, forum discussions/posts, choice polls, etc.

Web services is a better approach than exposing the database to an external system as it allows you to utilise the core APIs to improve integrity.